# excel display cell address of linked cell NOT value

Tags: excel

In excel I would like to display the cell address, ie `C5` of a linked cell in a different sheet, not the value of the cell itself

Example,

```
 I have two sheets A, B
 on Sheet A, I have value in column A1 "ALPHA"
 On Sheet A, I copy A1
 On Sheet B, in column B1, I paste link SheetA,A1
 Result -> display A1 not ALPHA
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure if it will do exactly what you want ...

```
Public Function GetCellAddress(ByVal objCell As Range) As String
    GetCellAddress = Replace(objCell.Address(), "$", "")
End Function
```

Add that into a new module within VBA.  If you're not familiar how to access the VBA editor, that's very Googlable.